# Directx12 Executeindirect instance count error

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, directx-12

When i change "gpu terrain rendering example"(Unity) from dx11 to dx12,the terrain is no longer displayed.

RenderDoc pic1:
https://smms.app/image/exSlcMTdRBHVZFb
RenderDoc pic2:
https://sm.ms/image/FPGMpkObKLSHwI3

the instancecount in Argument Buffer is 13F,but in ExecuteIndirect, the value is 15.What reason is this?